# Maintaining attribute table numeric field formatting when exporting using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I'm working with ArcGIS Pro 2.8. I have an attribute table that I would like to export as a .txt file with number values expressed in scientific notation. I've formatted the fields to be in scientific notation, but this is not maintained when exported, and it returns to normal numeric notation.

How can I fix this?

[image: My attribute table, which is formatted in scientific notation.]

Comment: Hello @Beck, can you add a screengrab of the attribute table showing the values in the subject field?

Comment: @YogeshChavan Added! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Highlight all the records in the table.

Do a Ctrl + Shift + C

Ctrl + V into a text or excel file. The scientific notation stays the same when I do it with ArcMap into both excel and text files.

Comment: @Beck The only way I could get the data out in scientific notation was as Adam had suggested, copy and paste. None of the export tools honour the formatting. May be you should head over to the ESRI community website and suggest it as an [idea](https://community.esri.com/t5/custom/page/page-id/arcgis-ideas)?

Comment: It should be noted that there appears to be a limit on how much data can be copied and pasted at one time. You may need to break up the copying and pasting into several batches if there is a large amount of data being moved.

Comment: This worked perfectly! It doesn't appear that my dataset is large enough for that to be a problem, but thank you for noting that for others.

Answer (score 0):

You could try switching the columns data class from a float or double to a string.

Answer (score 0):

A way to export attribute table to a .txt file. Is open the attribute table, then right-click the feature class. Open the attribute Table Click the Table Options arrow and click Select all. You would be converting the attribute table to the text file by using the table-to-table tool. The location of the new folder would be something like this c:\temp\mydata.

Try this code:

```py
# Import system modules
import arcpy
 
# Set environment settings
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/data"

# Make list of all tables in workspace
tables = arcpy.ListTables()

# Set local variables
outLocation = OutputFilePath = r"path\to\file"
with open(OutputFilePath, 'w') as outFile:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(AttributeTableOrFeatureClass, "*") as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            for val in row:
                outFile.write("%s," % val)
        outFile.write("\n")
```